# Which ORM should I use for Node.js and MariaDB with transaction support?

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, mariadb

Please don't close the question as I haven't been able to find answers anywhere.

Options are:

1. Waterline (popular but doesn't support transactions)
2. Sequelize (Popular but consensus is that it has become bloated and tough to follow)
3. node-orm2

Let me know if there are other better options.

Comment: In the long run, you will need to understand MariaDB and Transactions.  If you can't find a suitable ORM, use one to prototype, then abandon it.

Answer (score 1):

We've been using Knex.js and it's fantastic.  Initially we started w/ SQLite 3 but were able to quickly/easily migrate to MariaDB thanks to the ORM.

Per your requirements, it does have transaction support.

More info here: http://knexjs.org/